# positioning page numbers in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I am typesetting a book with several articles.  To create entries for each contribution, I am using

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\toctitle\newline{}{\hspace*{1cm} \textit{\cname}}}

\toctitle being the title of the contribution to appear in the table of contents, and \cname the name of the author(s).

With the package titletoc, I am formatting the entry in the table of contents thus:

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{\baselineskip}}{0em}{}{\hfill\thecontentspage}
```

This works fine.  The only problem is that the page number related to the entry should be bside `\toctitle`, not `\cname`.  This means the page number should be one line above the place it is now.

Thank you very much indeed for your help!

Sorry for the typo: the package is called titletoc, not titledoc.

Here comes a minimal example:

==>

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{\baselineskip}}{0em}{}{\hfill\thecontentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title of the first
  contribution\newline{}{\hspace*{1cm} \textit{Author of the first contribution}}}
Text of the first Contribution.

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title of the second
  contribution – a title much longer than you might expect, since it
  takes not only one, but two lines\newline{}{\hspace*{1cm} \textit{Author of the second contribution}}}
Text of the second Contribution.
\end{document}
```

<==

What I would like to achieve is that in the table of contents the page
numbers (3 and 5 respectively) be beside the last line of “Title of the
first contribution” and “Title of the second contribution – a title much
longer than you might expect, since it takes not only one, but two
lines” and not beside “Author of the first contribution” and “Author of
the second contribution”.

Many thanks again for your help

Rainer

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done and what the problem is. I've never heard of the `titledoc` package. Show us what you want the result to look like. Have you considered the `tocloft` package?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, splitting your ToC inputs into two, not one (see my last contribution).

```
% tocpagenosprob.tex  SE 636969

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{\baselineskip}}{0em}{}{\hfill\thecontentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title of the first
  contribution\newline{}{\hspace*{1cm} \textit{Author of the first contribution}}}
Text of the first Contribution.

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title of the second
  contribution – a title much longer than you might expect, since it
  takes not only one, but two lines\newline{}{\hspace*{1cm} \textit{Author of the second contribution}}}
Text of the second Contribution.


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title of the third
  contribution – a title much longer than you might expect, since it
  takes not only one, but two lines}
% adjust the 4mm space to suit
\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace*{4mm} \textit{Author of the third contribution}}
Text of the third Contribution.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped.  I think splitting the TOC inputs is the soberest approach.  That I will not follow it, is because it would require re-programming several macros.

On another list, it was suggested replacing

`\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{\baselineskip}}{0em}{}{\hfill\thecontentspage}`

by

`\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{\baselineskip}}{0em}{}{\hfill\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt]{\thecontentspage}}`

This is a bit hacky, of course, and as a general approach does have some limitations.  But it is doing what it is supposed to in this case and is the easiest way to go for me now.

Many thanks again to everyone who responded!